# SCSS :not(:last-child) but style is still applied to last element

Tags: css, sass

I have a div that contains different buttons and other divs working as a accordion.
I want to give all the buttons a border-bottom except for the last one.

The UI and html looks like this:

[image]

[image]

And I've tried using the `:not(:last-child)` selector, but as you can see in the first screenshot it isn't working and the last button still has the border-bottom.

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee !important;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Test</button>
<button class="accordion">Test</button>
<button class="accordion">Test</button>
<button class="accordion">Test</button>
<button class="accordion">Test</button>
```

(Also the snippet in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpn34myh))

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because `.accordion{&:not(:last-child){}}` is the same as `.accordion:not(:last-child)`, could you make a snippet ? I can't reproduce your problem, `:not(:last-child)` should work

Comment: @Cédric I've added a jsfiddle :)

Comment: For your **specific** example you could use `&:not(:last-of-type)` which means it will not apply if it is the last `button` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The children are of the parent div. And in your case, the last-child is `<div class="panel">`. A
better wording would be: The element *must* be the last element, regardless of selectors.

```css
.accordion:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="accordion">hi</div>
  <div class="accordion">hi</div>
  <div class="accordion">hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh wow that's strange. So if I have another div inside the parent-div that does not have the accordion class the last div with the accordion class will still have the style applied?

Comment: Yes and I think that is because CSS is parsing the document forward and doesn't return backwards. All selectors are like that.